# How do I create a new Maven lifecycle?

Tags: maven, lifecycle, maven-antrun-plugin

I have written an "Image Scaling" plugin in Maven that is working as expected. It doesn't directly participate in the build, but assists it with image scaling and file pre-processing; it needs to be run when we get new images only, not on every build. We run it as needed, like:

```
mvn image:scaling
```

All have been good until now.

Recently there's the need to "prepend" extra tasks to it, and I thought the `antrun` plugin could do trick with a few tasks, and it actually works well.

However, I can't find how to run the `antrun` plugin **just before** the `image:scaling`.

I was thinking I could set the phase of the `antrun` plugin to something like "pre-scaling"... but... where do I define the "pre-scaling" phase? If I need to create a new lifecycle, how do I do that?

Comment: If you do `mvn plugin:goal` you are not calling a life cycle so you have no order to do something before....

Comment: @khmarbaise Does that mean I should call the plugin without a goal? Something like `mvn image` ?

Comment: That is not possible on command line. The only way to do that you can bind your plugin to the life cycle...maybe using different goals of your plugin...